# Adding books causes weird transition of main site search box and profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When you set the focus of the textbox to find a book to add to your cv:

[image]

It causes the top header (search bar, profile image, badges, etc) to make a strange sliding transition and reappear.

Could this page also get some CSS / design loving?

Comment: Looks like it's on all the import pages.

Comment: @Max - Yes I meant to say that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed.

The search box in the top bar and the input box on the various import pages had the same element name ("q"), and some event handlers got confused.

For general CSS/design love, stand by for lots of love and awesomeness coming to SO Jobs in the near future.

Comment: I like the sound of that!