# Main header flies in or flashes when clicking a link

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

I've reported this bug or something similar many moons ago, and it was fixed. But this happens on another link now. When creating an alert, or editing your CV to add books, or add projects, or simply clicking change criteria the top header flies in. The section highlighted below flashes and flies back in due to some strange CSS / front end issue.

Try it...create a job alert and click the **change criteria** hyperlink. You'll see a sudden flash or shift of the page bringing the header back in...

[image]

Comment: Is this the similar bug you're referring to? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312865/adding-books-causes-weird-transition-of-main-site-search-box-and-profile

Comment: Yes same issue still not fixed right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These views no longer exist and I can't repro this anywhere else on the site so closing this as norepro. Drop a comment if you find it elsewhere and I'll rectify!